# Automapper with MediatR

Tags: c#, automapper, mediatr

I am in trouble when using Automapper with MediatR. I have a OrderCommand class like:

```
public class OrderCommand : IRequest<uint>
{
    public uint CountryId { get; set; }
    public List<OrderRequest> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderRequest
{
    public uint NumberItems { get; set; }
    public double? Width { get; set; }
    public double? Height { get; set; }
    public double? Length { get; set; }
    public string UserComment { get; set; }
}
```

and I have OrderDto like:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public uint? PackageId { get; set; }
    public uint? CountryId { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }

    public virtual PackageDto Package { get; set; }
}
```

and PackageDto like:

```
public class PackageDto
{
    public uint? NumberItems { get; set; }
    public double? Weight { get; set; }
    public double? Height { get; set; }
    public double? Length { get; set; }
    public string UserComment { get; set; }
}
```

So how do I map these Orders of OrderCommand to PackageDto of OrderDto when I am trying to create an Order? I'm a little bit confused about this situation.

Comment: Hii Fray, Do you have AutomapperProfile class in your project?

Comment: @ThomasRaj yes I have it.

Comment: Can you share your mapping code here Fray?

Comment: @ThomasRaj CreateMap<OrderRequest, PackageDto>();
            CreateMap<OrderCommand, OrderDto>();

Comment: Are you getting any errors or exceptions? If so please share it here so that we can have a better understanding

Comment: @ThomasRaj no I'm not getting any errors. I'm gonna use debugger to see what happened when mapping is done. I create a json and fill the parameters and send. When the debbuger started I saw the CountryId = 2 but Package = null. So that OrderCommand to OrderDto is correctly mapped but the OrderRequest to PackageDto didn't map correctly.

Comment: Can you show how you are mapping these two objects? The code which looks like this mapper.Map<DesitnantionClass>(sourceObject);. If you share the whole snippet it will be very useful

Answer (score 1):

You should create a map between `OrderRequest` and `OrderDto`

`CreateMap<OrderRequest, OrderDto>()`

Check out the following articles:
This one because you need to map to a nested property (PackageDto)
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html

This one because you are mapping an array
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html

In regards to mediator, there is nothing really special here.
The only thing that I should mention is that you should never map the command to the a dto, a command is a command not an entity in your domain.

Also, using uint is not adviseable unless you are writing unsafe code. Stick with int or long.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The question is that you are mentioned about the mapping between command and dto. How can I insert this command without mapping to dto? What should I do for the best practice?

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding. I meant you should map the `OrderRequest` to the Dto but not the actual command. You should consider Mediator to be completely out of scope for the case of mapping. Only maps models and dtos (things inside the command and things return from the command)